# Use different route namespace based on middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have the following code in my routes/web.php

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->middleware(['admin'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
});

Route::namespace('User')->middleware(['user'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
});
```

I wish to use the same uri "/posts" in both cases and keep the role logic (admin, user) out of the controllers, however, in this case, when I request the route "/posts" in always responds with the last one.

I can't seem to find information of what I am missing here.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is basically define two controllers for the same route. Which makes no sense. 

And it doesn't matter that in your case the controller in both cases is the same - Laravel will assume that you "changed your mind" and want `/posts` be handler in "user" namespace. I believe you should use 2 different routes.

Comment: so something like suggested below - /admin/posts and /user/posts? Is there really no cleaner way to separate the two logics?

Comment: I just realized you are probably using **different** controllers for those two actions (two different namespaces: `Admin/PostController` and `User/PostController`). So separating them by different routes makes a big sense and is I think the only solution. How should Laravel know which middleware to use based on URI itself, when you define two different sets of middlewares for the same URI? :)

Comment: My idea was that the request would enter the respective route group when the middleware passes so if let's say the 'admin' middleware does not pass it would not enter that group and try the next one.

Comment: Is there really no way I can re-use the same URI for two different things without having to resort to doing the check inside the method?

Comment: You could do it checking your conditions _before_ specifying the route, and then specify the route accordingly. But it's a poor solution and I would discourage it.
Remember that "middlewares" do not "pass" - they should maybe control access and possibly manipulate request, but I believe they are NOT designed for controlling request-flow to your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

use **prefix** for different route for **admin** and **user**

> /admin/posts

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin','middleware=>'admin','prefix' => 'admin'],function() {
    Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
});
```

> /user/posts

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'User','middleware=>'user','prefix' => 'user'],function() {
    Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
});
```

Comment: Is there no other way I can separate the two routes this or using a single controller and doing the check within each method?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'admin'],function (){
        Route::get('/posts',['uses'=>' PostController@posts','as'=>'posts.index']);


});


Route::group(['prefix'=>'user','middleware'=>'user'],function (){
        Route::get('/index',['uses'=>' PostController@posts','as'=>'posts.index']);


});
```